# Replace specific value in R

Tags: r, radix

I know it's something it should be easy but somehow I am stuck
I am trying to eliminate an outlier, replacing it for NA
dat is my data, and the value is what I want to modify

```
dat[dat$i_huvisfatin_v00 == 16527.98, "i_huvisfatin_v00"] <- NA

Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, dat$i_huvisfatin_v00 == 16527.98, "i_huvisfatin_v00",  : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames

dat[dat$i_huvisfatin_v00 == "16527.98", "i_huvisfatin_v00"] <- NA

Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, dat$i_huvisfatin_v00 == 16527.98, "i_huvisfatin_v00",  : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `dat$i_huvisfatin_v00[dat$i_huvisfatin_v00 == 16527.98] <- NA` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error message, it's either your `dat$i_huvisfatin_v00` column doesn't contain the value 16527.98, or it already have `NA` in the column.

`dat$i_huvisfatin_v00 == 16527.98` returns a logical vector, which cannot be treated as index itself if it contains `NA`. Use `which()` in the row index seems to solve the problem.

```
dat[which(dat$i_huvisfatin_v00 == 16527.98), "i_huvisfatin_v00"] <- NA
```

Comment: Exactly, the column already had NA in other rows. Thanks